# how to avoid overflow using a python block in GNUradio

Tags: satellites

I am implementing this code in an embedded python block in GNU Radio to received a stream of bits and extract a part of that stream, but I get "OsOOsOOsOOsOO" in the console and the CPU consumption just blows up.

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
import random
import math
from array import array
from gnuradio import gr
from itertools import islice


class CSP(gr.sync_block):  # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block
    """Embedded Python Block example - a simple multiply const"""

    def __init__(self):  # only default arguments here
        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='CSP decoder_01',   # will show up in GRC
            in_sig = [np.int8],
            out_sig = [np.int8])
        
        self.Array_priority = np.array([1, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
        self.Array_dest_address = np.array([0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0], dtype=np.uint8)
        self.Array_sour_addr = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1], dtype=np.uint8)
        self.Array_dest_port_address = np.array([0,0,1,0,1,1], dtype=np.uint8)
        self.Array_source_port_address = np.array([0,0,1,0,0,1], dtype=np.uint8)
        self.Array_reserved = np.array([0,0], dtype=np.uint8)
        self.Array_flag = np.array([0,1,1,1], dtype=np.uint8)
        #self.alfa = np.array([6, 4, 2, 7, 4, 5, 0, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 2, 3, 0, 4], dtype=np.uint8)
################################################################################################################################################################
    
    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
    
        input_data = np.array(input_items[0])
        output_data = np.zeros_like(input_data)
        L = len(input_data)

        #vectors sizes
        A = len(self.Array_priority)
        B = len(self.Array_dest_address)
        C = len(self.Array_sour_addr)
        D = len(self.Array_dest_port_address)
        E = len(self.Array_source_port_address)
        F = len(self.Array_reserved)
        G = len(self.Array_flag)
            
        for i in range(L -92+ 1):
            subsequence_0 = input_data[i:i+A]
            subsequence_1 = input_data[i+A:i+A+B]
            subsequence_2 = input_data[i+A+B:i+A+B+C]
            subsequence_3 = input_data[i+A+B+C:i+A+B+C+D]
            subsequence_4 = input_data[i+A+B+C+D:i+A+B+C+D+E]
            subsequence_5 = input_data[i+A+B+C+D+E:i+A+B+C+D+E+F]
            subsequence_6 = input_data[i+A+B+C+D+E+F:i+A+B+C+D+E+F+G]
            subsequence_7 = input_data[i+A+B+C+D+E+F+G:i+A+B+C+D+E+F+G+40]


            if (np.array_equal(subsequence_0, self.Array_priority)):
                if (np.array_equal(subsequence_1, self.Array_dest_address)):   
                    if (np.array_equal(subsequence_2, self.Array_sour_addr)):
                        if (np.array_equal(subsequence_3, self.Array_dest_port_address)): 
                            if (np.array_equal(subsequence_4, self.Array_source_port_address)): 
                                if (np.array_equal(subsequence_5, self.Array_reserved)): 
                                    if (np.array_equal(subsequence_6, self.Array_flag)):
                                        

                                        if i <= (L - len(subsequence_7)):
                                            output_data[i:i+len(subsequence_7)] = subsequence_7

                                            output_items[0][:] = output_data
                                            Z = len(output_data)    

    
        return Z
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this code work correctly on a recording? It's a bit confusingly complicated for what it seems to do, and my guess is that the python implementation hence is simply very slow. But I didn't understand it will enough to assess whether it is correct, i.e., whether it consumes all kinds of input

Comment: How are you calling the class? It could be a simple typo in your `main`.

Comment: Also, `Z` is never defined until it's set at the end of the loop, so if your `for` loop never runs that may also be part of the problem, and you are constricting the execution of the loop by the length of `input_data`. Are you certain that `input_data` is at least 92 items long?

Comment: GNUradio, sets a buffer for the block, and sends chunks of the data received into the block, so the input data is stablish according to the buffer set. In this code the for loop detects some specific streams into that chunk and then the streams detected are send to the output, and for that reason Z is the length of the stream detected and that data is   send to the output of the block.

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple `main` that calls your class manually? Basically black-boxing GNUradio so that you have a known input and expected output? You could then start it in debugging mode and step through the code and see where it's causing the issue. For it to send your CPU to 100% it makes me think there's either a memory leak or an infinite loop going on.